# Finish subclass activity from its superclass

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, superclass, activity-finish

**Consider the following scenario:** 
The class `TemplateActivity` extends `Activity`. Within `onResume()` it performs a validation of a boolean variable then, if false, it finishes the method and the activity, and starts a new activity, `OtherActivity`.

When the class `ChildActivity`, which extends `TemplateActivity`, runs, it waits for `super.onResume()` to finish and then continue no matter if its super needs to start the `Intent` or not.

**The question:**
Is there a way to terminate the `ChildActivity` when the `OtherActivity` needs to start from the `TemplateActivity`? Without implementing the validity check in the child class.

**Superclass:**

```
class TemplateActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(!initialized)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }

        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

**Subclass:**

```
class ChildActivity extends TemplateActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more elegant solution would be a slightly different approach to the class design:

1. Introduce a method `DoStuff()` (replace with sensible name) in the `TemplateActivity` . Do all the *// do stuff* bits there.
2. Call this method from the end of `TemplateActivity OnResume`
3. Override it in the child activity to extend it with the child activity *// do stuff* bits.
4. Do *not* override `onResume` in the ChildActivity.

This way, if the condition fires in TemplateActivity OnResume, none of the parent and child DoStuff will be done. The `ChildActivity`shouldn't have to know *anything* about this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you're trying to get:

```
class ChildActivity extends TemplateActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!isFinishing()) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to the validity check done from the child class which is what I'm trying to avoid, since I don't want to implement it throughout all the children.

Comment: yeah, you're right. I think what Paul-Jan suggests is a better approach.