# How to check state of app optimally?

Tags: android, android-activity

I develop android app. It needs save Internet data and login/password pair. I need to check that in every activity. How to do that optimally? My solution:

I create the BaseActivity class:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        checkRequirements();
    }

    private void checkRequirements() {
        if (needToCheckInternetConnection())
            checkInternetConnection();
            //check other requirements
    }

    private void checkInternetConnection() {
        if (!Updater.getInstance(context).checkInternetConnection()) {
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putSerializable(SplashScreenActivity.FIELD_ACTION, SplashScreenActivity.Action.SHOW_TEXT);
            data.putString(SplashScreenActivity.FIELD_TEXT, getString(R.string.splashScreenInternetNotAvailable));
            changeActivity(SplashScreenActivity.class, data);
        }
    }

    protected void changeActivity(Class<?> goTo, Bundle data) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, goTo);
        if (data != null)
            intent.putExtras(data);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

And I extends all activity classes from this.

But `finish()` not working. So, how to change that architecture or force to work the `finish()` method?

Comment: *But finish() not working.* - Can you describe what "not working" means? Does it crash? Do nothing?

Comment: Do nothing. I search about that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696149/finish-subclass-activity-from-its-superclass But this is bad I mean. The lot of extra code.